# If the user chose to invite a player from inside the game how can i differentiate this with an auto-match

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gamekit, invite

I initiate an online game like this:

```
    request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    request.minPlayers = 2;
    request.maxPlayers = 2;
    mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
```

When I receive the delegate method:

```
    - (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *)match
```

How to know if the player chose auto-match or invited a friend.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can tell at that point, but you could store what happened on your invite handler, something like:

```
    [GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite) {    
            if (acceptedInvite){
               // this player has accepted an invite
               acceptedInvite = YES;
               ....
            } else if (playersToInvite) {
               // this player is making an invite
              sentInvite = YES
              ...
            }
        };
```

If none of those variables are set to YES I think you can assume it was an automatch. Remember to set both to NO wherever is appropriate in your game.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the code for [GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler is never called in the invite side if the invite came from inside the game, but it is called if the invite is sent from outside the game. The problem is the invitee handler is called and expects a certain behavior from the invite device side that does not happen in this case.